# Problems logging into Mac after reinstalling older OS

Tags: macos, imac, user-account

I’m having problems with my late 2013 27 inch Mac and need some help.

Last night I tried to install a newer OS (Mojave) and it told me there was a disk management error (69854). I was previously on OS High Sierra.

I followed all the troubleshooting guides etc. and eventually had to
resinstall the OS in recovery mode. It took me all the way back to OS X Mavericks I think.

Unfortunately I don’t have a time machine backup. OS X is installed but it won’t let me go past the login page. When I try to enter my password the screen refreshes and nothing happens.

I’m inexperienced with this sort of stuff so any easy to follow help would be appreciated.

In terms of logging back in, I’ve repaired the “disc permissions” in disk utility but it’s done nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on AskDifferent. Please have a look at the Tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. On AskDifferent (AD) its best to ask **one** question per question. So e.g. edit this post to only ask about how to back up your drive and post another question asking about how to recover your Mac. Further, what exact mac model are we talking about? I highly doubt *it took you back to OSX* since that is either Mac OS X Cheetah from 2001 or OS X Montain Lion from 2012.

Comment: My exact Mac model is 27 inch late 2013.  

How can I check which OS it installed? It’s possible that it is Mavericks. Edit: it is Mavericks